# Issues and questions about jar file

Tags: java, user-interface, jar, executable-jar, java-11

I have some questions about jar files.

1. The bounds of the components change when I run the jar file from other computers. Is there anything I can do about it?
2. The jar file does not run on some computers, do I need the same JDK as the JDK that I have used to compile this jar file?
3. Because of section 2 I decided to make the jar an exe file with launch4j. The problem is that my program takes information from xls files, and after I convert my jar to exe, the information of the excel files saved in the program and when I changed the details from these excel files, this is not affected.

Comment: Point #1 is not understandable & point #2 is partially understandable. Please elaborate on these points.

Comment: And about the second part of point #2, you don't need JDK to run the jar file but JRE is enough for that matter.

Comment: point #1: for example I have a button with this bounds (100, 140, 30, 20) and in one computer when I run the jar file,this button shows in specific place on the screen and from another computer he changed his location and shows in another place on the screen(moves left).

Comment: point #2: On the computer where I created the jar file, I had to double click it to run it. But from other computers, double-clicking does not work, it is necessary to perform sample manipulations to run it, for example: run command from CMD. So I asked if this issue preform 'cause the JRE are different between those computers.